# Finding a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree at most 11 that interpolates $f(x)$ at $x_i (i=0,1,...,11)$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation

Q: Let

$$ f(x) = -2x^7 + 54321x^5 50x^3 + 2000x^2 - 10x + 0.000001, $$

and

$$ x_0 = 0.1, x_1 = 0.2, x_2 = 0.25, x_3 = 0.4, x_4 = 0.46, x_5 = 0.48, 
\\ x_6 = 0.50, x_7 = 0.52, x_8 = 0.6, x_9 = 0.7, x_{10} = 0.8, x_{11} = 1.25.$$

Find a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree at most 11 that interpolates $f(x)$ at $x_i (i=0,1,...,11)$.

A: Since $f(x) = −2x^7 + 54321x^5 + 50x^3 + 2000x^2 −10x + 0.000001 $ is a polynomial of degree $7$, so, $P(x) = f(x) = −2x^7 + 54321x^5 +50x^3 +2000x^2 − 10x +0.000001$.

I am slightly confused as to why a polynomial of degree $7$ such as $f(x)$ will suffice for the approximation and interpolation of data points in the range of $x_0$ to $x_{11}$.

Comment: What is your question? Is that Q&A pair given and you ask for clarification?

Comment: @DanielR Yes, I am asking as to why the answer is given in such a manner.

Comment: @Moo: you should say which data type was used for evaluation and interpolation. 32bit `float`, 64bit `double` or something else? The difference to $f$ is from interpolating the evaluation errors.

Comment: @Moo Ah its clearer to me now. So since $f(x)$ lies in the actual interpolating polynomial, is it right to set $f(x)$ as the interpolating polynomial of minimal degree for the 12 given points?

Comment: @Moo Unfortunately, no.. This question was posted as a problem during my course of study too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpolation polynomial has degree at most $11$ , but every smaller degree is possible. Consider the case, when all $y$-values coincide. Then , the degree is $0$.

More concrete : If pairwise different values $x_0,\cdots,x_n$ are given, then for every tuple $y_0,\cdots,y_n$ there exists a unique polynomial $f(x)$ with degree at most $n$, which satisfies $f(x_j)=y_j$ $j=0,\cdots ,n$.

In the case $y_0=\cdots=y_n$, the interpolating polynomial is $f(x)=y_0$. Every degree from $0$ to $n$ can occur.

The typical case is $deg(f)=n$, but not the only possible case.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you elaborate on the case when all $y$-values coincide? Also, the question did not state that $f(x)$ interpolates the 11 given points. In that case is there a problem with the question or is it just a huge conceptual misunderstanding on my part? Sorry for asking these as I'm still new to this topic..

Comment: Seems, that I misunderstood the question. I interpreted it in the way that $f(x)$ , a polynomial of degree $7$ already fits the $12$ points and you wonder whether this is possible.

Comment: @Stoner If I misunderstood your intent, please clarify what exactly confuses you.

Comment: Ah, so am I right to say that for these kind of questions, is it of the type where one has to find a polynomial of minimal degree that interpolates $f(x)$ will be $f(x)$ itself?

Comment: If $f(x)$ fits the points, it must be THE interpolating polynomial.

Comment: Yes I understand now. Truly sorry for the confusion and misconception..